# Logistics Regression in r

Tags: r, glm

Trying to perform Logistics Regression:

I converted the variable *price* to a qualitative variable.

```
pricecode = (ifelse(Airbnb$price >= 175, "high", "low"))

glm.fits = glm(pricecode["high"] ~ latitude + longitude + number_of_reviews + calculated_host_listings_count + availability_365, data = Airbnb, family = binomial)

summary(glm.fits)
```

Run code:

```
pricecode = (ifelse(Airbnb$price >= 175, "high", "low"))

glm.fits = glm(pricecode['high'] ~ latitude + longitude + number_of_reviews + calculated_host_listings_count + availability_365, data = Airbnb, family = binomial)

Error in model.frame.default(formula = pricecode["high"] ~ latitude +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'latitude')
```

Comment: Try just `pricecode~...` in the formula. If that fails make `pricecode` a factor.

Comment: Yeah - not sure what `pricecode['high']` is trying to achieve, but don't do it. Just `pricecode`.

Comment: It's possible that the OP desires "low" to be the base status so that the coefficients would represent the log-odds of seeing "high" versus "low". In which case the answer is to build the `pricecode` variable as a factor with levels `c("low", "high")`, which is the inverse of the default ordering.